# Jose4j: Unable to find a suitable verification key for JWS w/ header

Tags: jose4j

The verification fails because key_ops does not meet the criteria of the `SimpleJwkFilter` created from static method `filterForInboundSigned(JsonWebSignature jws)` in `SelectorSupport`. The public key looks something like this:

```
{
  "kid": "xxx",
  "use": "sig",
  "key_ops": [
    "sign"
  ],
  "kty": "xxx",
  "e": "xxx",
  "n": "xxx"
}
```

According to the `SimpleJwkFilter` "key_ops" either has to be null or contain the value "verify" to match the criteria.

Is there some way to customize this behaviour in jose4j? Maybe skip validation of "key_ops"?

Comment: As a side note: Shouldn't "sign" be a valid operation in this case, since "sign" and "verify" is a valid combination according to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7517#page-7 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver`, you could have simple little subclass of `HttpsJwks` which unsets the "key_ops" on each JWK before the filter sees them. That'd look something like this:

```
class MyHttpsJwks extends HttpsJwks
{
    public MyHttpsJwks(String location)
    {
        super(location);
    }

    @Override
    public List<JsonWebKey> getJsonWebKeys() throws JoseException, IOException
    {
        List<JsonWebKey> jsonWebKeys = super.getJsonWebKeys();
        for (JsonWebKey jwk : jsonWebKeys)
        {
            jwk.setKeyOps(null);
        }
        return jsonWebKeys;
    }
}
```

And then instantiate the resolver like `new HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver(new MyHttpsJwks("https://bad.example.com/jwks"));`

If you're using `JwksVerificationKeyResolver`, you can just do the same kind thing to the JsonWebKey list before instantiating the resolver with it. Similar preprocessing on the list will also work, if you are using `VerificationJwkSelector` or the SimpleJwkFilter directly.

FWIW, according to RFC7517 the "use" and "key_ops" parameters shouldn't be used together and if they are, they are supposed to convey the same meaning.  I would argue that the JWK in question isn't honoring that because the "key_ops" of "sign" says the key can be used to compute a digital signature while a "use" of "sig" says that the key can be used for digital signature operations in general (sign or verify).

Comment: did not help but interesting to read